# Too many riley riddles? Then here's another one

Tags: riddle, word

```
My prefix is what you fall when you get sick

My first infix is what you say when you don't know what to say

My second infix is a hotel without the last letter 

My suffix is a number between one and 10,

and it is also past tense of a verb
```

Always a better day with more Riley riddles :)

Comment: Why was this given a downvote? I quite liked it (and sadly can't upvote myself because of my daily voting limit).

Comment: Hmmm, I have no clue

Comment: It's fine, I got two reputations from the accept and -2 from the downvote :l

Comment: I remember there was another riley riddle where (ROT13) gur nafjre jnf Npgvavhz, juvpu unf na HZ nf vgf fhssvk. Creuncf fbzrobql gubhtug lbh jrer abg bevtvany orpnhfr gur "svefg vasvk" cneg fbhaqrq n yvggyr fvzvyne? Or maybe it was because this was too easy, but I have had plenty of easy riddle (e.g. [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68972/youth-is-inevitably-the-nature-of-yielding-adulthood-nurture-it-greatly)) which have had some upvotes. I guess it is just users' taste, then.

Comment: Well, what else do I call it? The one st infix?

Comment: Hahah, well, I wouldn't be too fussed, but that's just me. Just be patient, and I am sure someone would like it enough to upvote :)

Comment: Maybe you tomorrow? :D

Comment: Yeah, alright then. I have to wait $20$ hours before I can upvote. I will let you know that I have, but until then, $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I'm also working on this one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69812/a-connection-between-riley-riddles-and-i

Comment: Apologies if it is a bit difficult (unless you like difficult puzzles / have time for this one / not finding it difficult at all). Would you like me to give out a hint, perhaps? :) **Edit:** Well, darn, as soon as I write this comment, someone answers it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Illuminate

Prefix:

> One falls Ill

first infix:

> "um"

Second infix, A hotel without an E is:

> an Inn

Lastly a number between 1 and 10:

> 8, or ate

Comment: *Hello!* Congratulations to your very first answer on the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! Not only was this answer great, but it was $\color{green}{\text{accepted}}\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$ which not many users tend to achieve as their first answer! Well done! Since you are new, I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and check out the following three sections in particular: *Asking* (e.g. [**here**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), *Answering* and *Our model* (e.g. the **Code of Conduct**). Hope you enjoy! :D