# A Kidnapped Friend

Tags: cipher

One friend of mine has been inactive over the past few weeks.

One day, my friend sent me this:

> Hello there, I have been kidnapped! I secretly made this message in order to get you here. Here is the message:
>
> > Australian commercial television network (3) 
> >     Same score (3)
> >     Become visible (4)
> >
> > `_ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ Nikoli`
> >
> > [image: cryptic country]

*Where is my friend?*

Comment: And here I was just watching the movie *Saw* (2004)... what's with the kidnappings today?

Comment: I believe the fourth grid is ambiguous. (+1 though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three clues resolve to

> TEN, TIE, and SHOW.

This hints at

> "Tentai Show", also called "Spiral Galaxies": a logic puzzle genre from Nikoli.

Solving the ten lower grids in that way gives

> **SURAT, INDIA**. However, the second grid has no solution: I imagine the rightmost white dot should be half a cell lower.
>  [image]

Comment: Already answered? Wow. $(+1)$

Comment: @user477343 Of course it is, it's Deusovi :P

Comment: @PotatoLatte he did that to [one of my riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68972/youth-is-inevitably-the-nature-of-yielding-adulthood-nurture-it-greatly), too, but I have to admit that one was easier (or if not, *much* easier) than this puzzle :D