# Riddle 2: What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have very sharp teeth and I like to eat different types of meat
>   My tail is very long and green
>   My skin is one of the oldest skins you'll ever see
>   I like to live in lakes and rivers and I'm scaring some people

What am I?

Comment: I like this riddle... but if you head to [one of my riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68972/youth-is-inevitably-the-nature-of-yielding-adulthood-nurture-it-greatly), there is a comment below by one of the moderators, @Deusovi $\diamondsuit$ who says the following words: *"I downvoted because this is a very straightforward riddle, with seemingly no attempt to obscure any information. It's closer to "identify this object" than an actual riddle."* I believe your riddle risks falling under what he said...

Comment: This is a good point @user477343 -- you'll notice that a lot of my explanations for the clues you gave were "This is also true..." Obscuring the information to make things a bit more complicated definitely helps improve riddle quality!

Comment: @El-Guest I feel slightly bad for raising the point, because I do personally like the riddle and do not wish to discourage the OP from making riddles (or anyone for that matter!). It is just that from my experience, there is a certain standard that must be met on this site, especially when making riddles; there are heaps of puzzlers on this site that see riddles just about everyday (myself included) :)

Comment: @user477343 you are entirely correct though, and your feedback is always so positive! :D I'm definitely agreeing with you on this one; usually there's some sort of wordplay or twist in the puzzle; this one felt more like a straightforward description. It was a good early puzzle but there's always room to grow! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you

> a crocodile?

I have very sharp teeth and I like to eat different types of meat.

> Crocodiles have sharp teeth and eat meat

My tail is very long and green.

> Also true of crocodiles

My skin is one of the oldest skins you'll ever see.

> Also true of crocodiles

I like to live in lakes and rivers and I'm scaring some people

> Also true of crocodiles

Comment: Yeah!Just have to wait 9 mins.